# Handling AJAX errors in React.componentDidMount

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, reactjs

According to Facebook, the best way to load initial data for a React component is to make an AJAX request in the componentDidMount function:

https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/initial-ajax.html

something like so:

```
           componentDidMount: function () {
                var self = this;
                Store.fetch()
                    .done(function () {
                        if (self.isMounted()) {
                            self.setState(getLatestState());
                        }
                    })
                    .fail(function (err) {
                        throw err;
                    }).always(function(){
                        Store.addChangeListener('rc-listen',self._onChange);
                    });
                },
```

what is the best way to handle errors in this case? Since AJAX is async, shouldn't componentDidMount take a callback as an argument?

Comment: If you forget about the implementation for a moment, what would like the user to see if the request fails? A blank screen, an error message? To handle this you can just set a state of 'load failed' and conditionally show an error message.

Comment: David, yeah, but that means that I have the same error logic in all my componentDidMount functions. With a callback, I can handle all the errors with the same code. Dontcha think?

Comment: If you do need an AJAX request in each individual component but want to share error-handling, you can pass a method down from a parent component, then in each component call `this.props.handleAjaxError(err)` or whatever. But I have to wonder if you're not better off putting all your AJAX requests in a single component (or do server-side rendering and populate a store if that's an option for you)

Answer (score 1):

First, when you use componentDidMount, the component was inserted into DOM and is ready to use (add events for elements, access dom elements,...). So, component at this point is always mounted.

Second, if ajax request is success you change the state to show the updated data BUT if ajax request is fail you could change the state to show and error message to the user (for example and, if you want, send the error to your server to keep a error history).

Comment: I agree, it doesn't make that much sense, but the React docs suggest to use " if (this.isMounted()) ", look at the link in the OP

Comment: Hi @AlexMills anyway, this function "isMounted" could be removed in a future: "It may be removed entirely in a future version of React." (from my case I never had troubles not using it on componentDidMount)